# Is there a way to compare two methods by function rather than value?

Tags: java, compare

Is there a way to compare if two methods are equivalent by function (i.e. they do the same thing) rather than equivalent by value (i.e. all of the code in the method is the same) ?

For example these two methods are coded differently, but perform the same function.

```
public int doIt(int a, int b) {
    a = a + 1;
    b = b + 1;
    return a + b;
}

public int doIt2(int z, int x) {
    int total = z + x + 2;
    return total;
}
```

I was looking for a way to do this in Eclipse, but am interested if this is even possible beyond a trivial method.

Comment: Call them and check their return value.

Comment: Yes, and that's the way you know they do the same thing, unless you're defining `do the same thing` in some strange way.

Comment: I've closed this question, because it is not java related, it is general question from CS theory. See canonical question, it should give you a clue of understanding this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to be 100% is to mathematically prove it

There are ways:

1- [Theorem proving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving)

2- [Model Checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_checking)

and etc

Although these approaches can be very hard, sometime it might take days to prove it even for trivial programs and even days to produce the adequate abstraction level.

There are some heuristic approaches but obviously they are not 100% accurate (heuristic)

A simple heuristic approach would be to try both methods for 1000 inputs and see if the results are the same

EDIT:

here is a list of Model Checker I found on Wikipedia. I haven't used any of them, they may not be exactly what you are looking for.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_model_checking_tools

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring side effects, 2 functions will be functionally equivalent if for the same input, they produce the same output.

This will only work for pure code though. There's no way I know of to monitor for side effects in general since the side effects a function carries out could be anything.

Note, there wouldn't be a way to completely verify this without testing every possible input. If the input is just a limited Enum, that might be easy. If it's 2 integers though for example, the total number of combinations would be huge.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the purpose of refactoring is to have a function behave the same before and after it is refactored. Developers generally do this by creating extensive unit tests, testing both normal, edge, and exception cases.

In the OP's two functions to be compared, `doIt` and `doIt2`, they might usually return the same answer, given any integer inputs a and b. Unit testing would demonstrate this.

But what if a or b were the largest integer that Java could store, `MAX_VALUE`?

What if there were a side effect from `a=a+1`?

In these cases, the two functions may appear similar on the surface, but yield different results.